# Emacs 24 function definition is void: ruby-indent-command

Tags: ruby, emacs

On a fresh installation of emacs 24.3.1, I can't edit ruby files because hitting return results in an error,

> Symbol's function definition is void: ruby-indent-command

What's it supposed to be defined to? This happens on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 with `apt-get install emacs`. I have a few AWS instances with it so I'd rather not do something complicated like installing a different ruby mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not defined anywhere in Emacs versions 24.2 to 24.5 (those are the only ones I've checked right now), nor is it referenced anywhere.

So you should look into your config and figure out why pressing `RET` results in an attempt to call it.

Comment: ...automatically propagating old .emacs files leads to strange things. I feel dumb.